# DeclareOption inside a \foreach loop

Tags: package-writing

I'm making a new package, and want to simplify the following lines in a .sty file using \foreach

```
\DeclareOption{aaa}{ \def\x{1} }
\DeclareOption{bbb}{ \def\x{2} }
\DeclareOption{ccc}{ \def\x{3} }
```

I tried the following

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \i/\j in {aaa/1, bbb/2, ccc/3}{
   \DeclareOption{\i}{ \def\x{\j}}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

But, it doesn't define \x.

In contrast, the following works

```
\def\i{aaa}
\def\j{1}
\DeclareOption{\i}{ \def\x{\j}}
```

Maybe the problem has something to do with the implementation of \foreach loop, however I can't figure it out.

Comment: Local versus global. The braces `{...}` make the `\def\x` local. Use `\gdef\x`. But the DeclareOption command would be being set locally, too, I would expect. Note that `\i` logically cannot be made global (since it is being used locally as a loop macro) with the code snippet as-is. Unrelated `\i` is already defined globally to typeset a dotless-i glyph. and `\j` does dotless-j, so you lose them if you redefine globally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pgf `\foreach` places each iteration in a local group so it is often an unsuitable looping construct for programming tasks.

There are many other loop macros that do not introduce groups eg the `expl3` clist mappings, or the `\loop` macro in the format or you can simply execute a list directly without any explicit loop macro.

This will iterate over a space separated list of pairs until it gets to a blank line for example

test.sty

```
\long\def\zz #1/#2 #3{%
   \ifx\par#3%
   \else
   \DeclareOption{#1}{\def\x{#2}}%
   \expandafter\zz\expandafter#3\fi
}

\zz aaa/1 bbb/2 ccc/3

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

So this sets `\x` to 2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bbb]{test}
\typeout{x=\x}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\foreach` executes every item in the loop in a group, so it's useless for this application.

Here's an example with a different loop:

```
%%% file declareoptions.sty
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \DeclareOptionsWithFormat #1 #2
 {% #1 is a list of items of the form {<optionname>}{<text>}
  % #2 is code that will become \DeclareOption{<optionname>}{<code>}
  % The <code> here should depend on #1, which will be replaced
  % with the current <text> in the loop
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__declareoptionswithformat_aux:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \__declareoptionswithformat:nn ##1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__declareoptionswithformat:nn
 {
  \DeclareOption{#1}{\__declareoptionswithformat_aux:n {#2}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareOptionsWithFormat{
  {aaa}{1},
  {bbb}{2},
  {ccc}{3}
}{\def\x{#1}}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

If we run the test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbb]{declareoptions}

\show\x
```

we get

```
> \x=macro:
->2.
```

If you have LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01, you'll need

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
```

in `declareoptions.sty`.